# Where does configuration data go in Redux?

Tags: redux

I'm wondering how to deal with configuration data. What I'd like to do is, keep configuration data in an object tree and save it to local storage when the user exits settings.

Should I contain configuration data inside a dedicated reducer or just treat it as ordinary application state and keep it spread out over reducers where it is actually used?

Comment: What kind of configuration are you talking about? Is it static or modifiable by end user?

Comment: The latter, stuff you'd find on a settings page.

Comment: of course you will need to store the changes in app state, also in local storage (to maintain the data if a reload happens), and also sync it with server..

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on how your app is using all those configurations. Are they set on a single page like a Settings page or spread across different modules of your app?

It makes sense to store it in a single reducer especially if in your backend it is also stored in a single table or object in db.

Comment: Yes, there is a dedicated area ('Settings'). For the time being, I keep that data in a single reducer. The state for that reducer implements `ISettingsState`, which extends `ISettings`. `ISettings` is the raw data as it goes into local storage, `ISettingsState` also keeps track of whether settings have been loaded etc.